# Idiomatic line-by-line capture of stdout in Clojure

Tags: logging, clojure, stdout

I have some code (which I can't modify) that calls various API endpoints over the course of several seconds, printing lines of information to stdout at each step. I'd like to redirect the lines that are printed to stdout to a custom logging function instead.

Ordinarily, if I were forced to call code whose stdout-writing side effects I don't control, I might wrap it in a call to `with-out-str`. In this case, I'm looking for a solution that allows me to intercept each individual line *when* it's printed, instead of after the function is done (which is what `with-out-str` would allow me to do).

Is there an idiomatic way to do this, perhaps some kind of `java.io.Writer` that invokes a callback upon flushing each line?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
(defn slowly-print-many-lines []
  (dotimes [i 10]
    (println "Printing line number" (inc i))
    (Thread/sleep 1000)))


(let [on-line-printed (fn [printed-line]
                        (my-logger/info printed-line))]
  (binding [*out* (callback-writer on-line-printed)]
    (slowly-print-many-lines)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write your own wrapper class of `PrintStream`, then use `java.lang.System/setOut` and `setErr` to reassign the value of `System.out` & `System.err`.

You can see a related usage in the [Tupelo Clojure library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo) macro `with-system-out-str` & friends, which is different than the Clojure `with-out-str`:

```
 (defmacro with-system-out-str
   "Evaluates exprs in a context in which JVM System/out is bound to a fresh
   PrintStream.  Returns the string created by any nested printing calls."
   [& body]
   `(let [baos# (ByteArrayOutputStream.)
          ps#   (PrintStream. baos#)]
      (System/setOut ps#)
      ~@body
      (System/setOut System/out)
      (.close ps#)
      (.toString baos#)))
```